# I need help in understanding the definition of a plane wave propagating at an angle from the horizontal

Tags: waves

I am reading [THIS](https://www.worldcat.org/title/parabolic-equation-methods-for-electromagnetic-wave-propagation/oclc/43632119) book and there is the following definition of a plane wave propagating at angle $\alpha$ from the horizontal:

$$\psi(x,z)=\text{exp}\left(ikx\text{ cos}(\alpha)+ikz\text{ sin}(\alpha)\right)$$

where $k$ is the wave number

Could someone derive this for me? I don't know where it comes from, and it isn't explained in the book. Thanks

[image]

Comment: since there is no time in your equation it can not be a propagating wave. Is your expression a exact copy?

Comment: Do you know that plane waves can be represented by $e^{i (\mathbf{k\cdot r} - \omega t)}$?

Comment: Trula, yes, I copied it exactly, I added a photo if it helps.

And Philip, I am not I haven't seen that definition before either.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of a unit plane wave, at fixed time is:

$$\psi(\vec r) = e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r} $$

The phase is:

$$ \phi(\vec r) = \vec k \cdot \vec r $$

The gradient of the phase:

$$ \nabla \phi(\vec r) = \vec k$$

is the would-be direction of propagation.

The book defines "an angle alpha from the horizontal" to be:

$$ \hat k = \cos(\alpha)\hat x + \sin(\alpha) \hat z$$

so that the full expression with the wave-vector $ \vec k \equiv k\hat k$ is:

$$ \phi(\vec r) = k\hat k\cdot \vec r= k( \cos(\alpha)\hat x + \sin(\alpha) \hat z) \cdot (x\hat x + y\hat y + z\hat z) $$

$$ = k ( \cos(\alpha)x + \sin(\alpha) z)$$